# How to split one row into separate ones sas

Tags: split, sas, row

I have a data set (Table A) like below:

```
Location_id |  Arrival_Date | Length_of_Stay | Demand   | 

------------+---------------+--------------- +----------+

   L_1      | 23-JUL-16     |  1             | 5        |

   L_1      | 23-JUL-16     |  2             | 7        |

   L_1      | 23-JUL-16     |  3             | 8        |

   L_1      | 23-JUL-16     |  4             | 3        |

   L_1      | 24-JUL-16     |  1             | 3        |

   L_1      | 24-JUL-16     |  2             | 2        |

   L_1      | 24-JUL-16     |  3             | 4        |

   L_1      | 25-JUL-16     |  1             | 5        | 

 ...........  ............    .............   .......
```

I would like to transfer to the following table:

```
Location_id |  Stay_Date |  Demand   | 

 L_1        | 23-JUL-16  |23= 5+7+8+3| (Arrival JUL-23, 4 Length_of_stays)

 L_1        | 24-JUL-16  |27= 7+8+3+3+2+4| (Arrival JUL-24, 3 Length_of_stays and Arrival JUL-23, 3 Length_of_stays)

 L_1        | 25-JUL-16  |22= 8+3+2+4+5|(JUL-23, 2 length_of_stays; JUL-24, 2 length_of_stays; JUL-25, 1 length_of_stay)

 L_1        | 26-JUL-16  |  7        |(JUL-23, 1 length_of_stay)
```

Where demand is measured as Stay_Date, which is calculated according to Arrival_Date and Length_of_Stay.

How can I make it in SAS? Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? All you need to do is 1) generate a new variable and 2) summarise by it.

Comment: How is Demand calculated? Is the bottom table supposed to align with the sample table? Please post what you've tried. Proc SQL or proc means are good places to start

Comment: Read about proc summary or Proc means in SAS, it you don't get it, come back again, Hint Use: location_id and arrival_date in class section

Comment: Please explain in detail how the second table is calculated from the first table.  What you've provided is insufficient

Comment: @NEOmen Sorry I didn't explain clearly, I just updated my question, how the demand of 'Stay_Night' is calculated. I might need a new variable.

Comment: @user667489 Thanks! You are right, and I think I have question on how the new variable is calculated.

Comment: @Reeza  I just updated my question. Thanks!

Comment: @DCR I just updated my question, thanks!

Comment: your formula is not making sense  to me, Can you be more elaborate?

Comment: @NEOmen  For example, date 23-Jul-16, demand is calculated by adding the first 4 rows. Since the first row spend 1 day, the second row spend 2 days, the third spend 3 days, and the fourth spend 4 days; and they are all staying at 23-Jul-16.  And date 24-Jul-16 is calculated by adding rows 2,3,4 and rows 5,6,7 since they all stay at 24-Jul-16. Thanks!

Comment: The 'corrections' posted don't align with the data even more. I don't understand it at all now, you're data is Jul but you're referencing Jan in your comments?

Comment: @Reeza Thanks for reminding! Updated again. Sorry and Jan was a typo, please all regard as January. And my last comment has more explanations if this works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still haven't explained your question well at all. 
My assumptions:

- Each line is a record of a stay and the demand level for that stay.
- If a stay is multiple days (length of stay > 1) then create a record
  for each day of the stay.
- Adding up each of these records generates
  your total demand on each day at the hotel/facility.

You also should have posted sample data in a data step.

```
data have;
informat arrival_date anydtdte.;
format arrival_date date9.;
infile cards dlm='|';
input Location_id $  Arrival_Date  Length_of_Stay  Demand  ;  

cards;
   L_1      | 23-JUL-16     |  1             | 5        |
   L_1      | 23-JUL-16     |  2             | 7        |
   L_1      | 23-JUL-16     |  3             | 8        |
   L_1      | 23-JUL-16     |  4             | 3        |
   L_1      | 24-JUL-16     |  1             | 3        |
   L_1      | 24-JUL-16     |  2             | 2        |
   L_1      | 24-JUL-16     |  3             | 4        |
   L_1      | 25-JUL-16     |  1             | 5        | 
;
run;

*Create a record for each day of the visit;
data temp;
set have;
format stay_date date9.;

do i=1 to length_of_stay;
    stay_date=arrival_date-1 + i;
    output;
end; 
run;

*summarize the totals;
proc sql;
create table want as
select stay_date, sum(demand) as total_demand
from temp
group by stay_date
order by stay_date;
quit;
```

Comment: Thanks! I just tried and I think the do loop is helpful!